# How to set WPF application icon using ico file from subfolder

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to change the default icon of my WPF application. I have an ico file that I would like to use in an *Icons* folder.

I tried to set the application's assembly icon inside the `application.csproj` file. More information can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.icon?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#remarks)

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ApplicationIcon>icon.ico</ApplicationIcon>
  </PropertyGroup>
  ...

  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="Icons\icon.ico" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

But when I try this I am getting an error: `Could not find file`
It is looking for the `icon.ico` file in the directory that contains the csproj file and **NOT** the *Icons* directory.

> Is there a way to have my ico file be in a sub directory called *Icons* and use `<ApplicationIcon>` to set the application's icon?

Comment: Where is this `icons` folder? Inside your project directory?

Comment: @Sach yes. The *Icons* folder is in the same folder as the `application.csproj` file

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, add the icon to the folder the 'right' way. That is, *from the Solution Explorer*, right click the `Icons` folder, and go to `Add --> Existing Item` and select the icon file that is somewhere else other than the `Icons` folder. This will copy the icon into your project directory as a resource file. Once copied, right click on the icon again from the Solution Explorer, click `Properties` and verify that the `Build Action = Resource` is set.

Then, again from the `Solution Explorer` right click your project and select `Properties`. It will open up the following window:

[image]

And in the `Resources` section, select `Icon and manifest` and in the `Icon` drop down, select the icon you just added to your project.

[image]

Now the icon will appear in the application window.

[image]

And also in your taskbar:

[image]

Comment: I think the first sentence summed up the problem in my situation: "the right way". I wasn't moving the image file the right way. Thank you for taking time to respond!

Answer (score 2):

We can do it in an easy way. First, add the icon to the folder. That is, from the Solution Explorer, right click, and go to Add --> Existing Item and select the icon file that is somewhere else other than the Icons folder. This will copy the icon into your project directory as a resource file. Once copied, go to MainWindow.xaml tab. Click on the window, then select properties from the right corner as shown in below image, then select the icon
from drop down. Done! build the solution.
[image]

Note: This only sets icon for the window when run, Not to the exe.

Answer (score 0):

Here two steps needed. Above solution from Sach shows an icon assignment to MyApp.exe file. And N.Siva shows Step#2)

### 1) Icon and Manifest

-> Select Icon -> It will show on the explore for MyApp.exe file

### 2) Assign Icon that shows up on taskbar

when application is running, select MyApp Form, on Proerties of it, there an Icon. Select the Icon that you want. This is tested in VS2017.